# How to add CSS .nex() property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When adding the class "playing" then I will add the next li tag custom CSS.
Please read my code, my you understand

See my code.

```
   <ul>
    <li class="playing">li (sibling)</li>
    <li id="head">li <b class="block">(sibling)</b></li>
    <li>li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
  </ul>
```

JQuery :

```
$(".playing").next("#head .block").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

Jquery not working next() property :(

Comment: Side note, id's cannot be repeated.  So the use of next to find an id could be replaced with just looking the id up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".playing").next("#head").find(".block").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="playing">li (sibling)</li>
  <li id="head">li <b class="block">(sibling)</b></li>
  <li>li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
  <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
  <li>li (sibling)</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is looking for a sibling that is a block, not a siblings child. You need to pull the `.block` out and do a `find()`

```js
$(".playing").next("#head").find(".block").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="playing">li (sibling)</li>
    <li id="head">li <b class="block">(sibling)</b></li>
    <li>li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
  </ul> 
JQuery :
```

Answer (score 1):

`.next` returns the related sibling on same level. `.block` is the child of `#head` and is not on same level.

Use `find` after `next` in this way:

```js
    $(".playing").next("#head")
                 .find(".block")
                 .css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul>
    <li class="playing">li (sibling)</li>
    <li id="head">li <b class="block">(sibling)</b></li>
    <li>li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
  </ul>
```